# Is there a way to have a Vim function create mappings for you?

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a function in Vim that is capable of creating mappings for me (so I don't have to type out very similar commands over and over in my config).

Take these mappings as an example:

```
onoremap <buffer> in( :<c-u>execute "normal! /(\r:noh\rvi("<cr>
onoremap <buffer> in[ :<c-u>execute "normal! /[\r:noh\rvi["<cr>
onoremap <buffer> in{ :<c-u>execute "normal! /{\r:noh\rvi{"<cr>
```

I would like to be able to do instead something like:

```
CreateNextIn('(')
CreateNextIn('[')
CreateNextIn('{')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. It should be something like this:

```
function! CreateNextIn(foo) abort
  execute 'onoremap <buffer> in'.a:foo.' :<c-u>execute "normal! /[\r:noh\rvi'.a:foo.'"<cr>'
endfunction
```

Then you create your mappings with it like:

```
call CreateNextIn('(')
call CreateNextIn('[')
call CreateNextIn('{')
```